# Is a real random variable's moment-generating function the Laplace-Stieltjes transform of its CDF?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration, moment-generating-functions, stieltjes-integral

Wikipedia gives that the [moment-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Calculation) for a real random variable $X$ with cumulative distribution function $F$ equals

> $M_x(t) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\, dF(x)$, using the [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

It defines the (bilateral) [Laplace-Stieltjes transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Stieltjes_transform#Real-valued_functions) of a real function $g(x)$ to be

> a [Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration)  of the form $\{\mathcal{L}^*g\}(s) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-sx} dg(x)$.

These two definitions look identical to me, except for the sign of the argument and the slightly different type of integral. Is the choice of Riemann-Stieltjes vs. Lebesgue-Stieltjes important here? Are there any CDFs for which these two quantities disagree (beyond the opposite sign of the argument)?

Comment: The (improper) Riemann–Stieltjes integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}g(x)$ coincides with the Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral if the integrand $f(x)$ is non-negative and continuous and the integrator $g$ is monotone increasing and right-continuous. This is indeed the case for the integral defining $M_X(t)$.